# ValueError: column_name: input_tensor dtype must be string or integer. dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, networking, classification, packet

I'm trying to create a packet classifier using packet flows in Tensorflow 2.4.0. When training my model using tf.estimator, I get the error:

```
    ValueError: column_name: avg_piat input_tensor dtype must be string or integer. dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>.
```

Here is a portion of the data set which contains avg_piat:
[image]

I've tried doing everything from similar questions but nothing seems to be working. I'm thinking it might be from how I create my feature columns but I'm not sure. Here are how I create my feature columns. Thanks in advance.

```
min_piat = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("min_piat",hash_bucket_size=1000)
max_piat = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("max_piat",hash_bucket_size=1000)
avg_piat = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket("avg_piat",hash_bucket_size=1000)
```

***## Edit ##***

I solved the issue. When I defined a feature column for avg_piat I changed it from a hash bucket to a numerical column:

```
avg_piat = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("avg_piat")
```

Comment: When defining the column have you tried putting .astype("int32") at the end?

Comment: Can you share your model definition?

Comment: @DwightFoster thanks for responding. I tried doing that by `df.astype({'avg_piat': 'int32'}).dtypes` . It then said that the column avg_piat was now a float64. However when I ran the rest of the code I got the same error.

Comment: @Lescurel Thanks for responding. This is my model definition. `model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols)` . However this is where I'm getting my error `model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=120)` .

Answer (score 0):

Providing solution here for the benefit of community.

> Issue has been resolved, after changing feature column for `avg_piat`
> from a hash bucket to a numerical column as
> `avg_piat = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("avg_piat")` ((paraphrased from Will)